# What kind of machine learning models fit data of this kind?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, feature-engineering, functional-data-analysis

I have been working with a manufacturing process. It would be very efficient to build a machine learning model for the kind of data that I have. So, my dataset has typically three inputs.

| VAl_1 | VAl_2 | Val_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 | 2 |
| 12 | 3 | 3 |
| 14 | 4 | 1 |

VAL_1 can be from 8 to 12 and it is a continuous variable. 
VAL_2 is a number from 1 to 4. (not continuous) 
VAL_3 is a number from 1 to 3. (not continuous)

The output is like a function $y = f(x)$, where $x$ is a continuous value in the range $(0,1)$

For example, a sample row of my dataset is as follows:

| VAl_1 | VAl_2 | Val_3 | y(0) | y(0.2) | y(0.4) | y(0.6) | y(0.8) | y(1.0) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 1 | 1 | 0.00025 | 0.0856 | 0.8946 | 0.00524 | 0.872 | 0.5242 |

I want to build a model that predicts y(x) given VAL_1, VAL_2, VAL_3

How to deal with features that are both continuous and not continuous in the same model?

Any ideas or thoughts on how I should proceed with such a dataset would be greatly appreciated.

I did try the following:

Normalized VAL_1.
I tried encoding features VAL_2, VAL_3.

Normalized the values of y(x).

Tried to fit linear regression, polynomial regression models. But the value of R_square is around 68%.

Are there any better ways to improve the model?

Comment: Are `VAL_2, VAL_3` integers (counts) or categorical? Else, look into functional data analysis,  see tag [tag:functional-data-analysis]

Comment: You can use a gradient boosted model - regression, I think. It can handle both continuous and categorical input.

Comment: VAL_1, VAL_2 are just integers.